# Clickable widgets in android

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-widget

The developer documentation has seemed to have failed me here.  I can create a static widget without thinking, I can even create a widget like the analogue clock widget that will update itself, however, I can not for the life of me figure out how to create a widget that reacts to when a user clicks on it.  Here is the best code sample that the developer documentation gives to what a widget activity should contain (the only other hint being the API demos, which only creates a static widget):

```
public class ExampleAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExampleActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener to the button
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget_provider_layout);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);

            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current App Widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

from: [The Android Developer Documentation's Widget Page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

So, it looks like pending intent is called when the widget is clicked, which is based off of an intent (I'm not quite sure what the difference between an intent and a pending intent is), and the intent is for the ExampleActivity class.  So I made my sample activity class a simple activity that when created, would create a mediaplayer object, and start it (it wouldn't ever release the object, so it would eventually crash, here is it's code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound);
    mp.start();
}
```

However, when I added the widget to the home screen, and clicked on it, nothing played, in fact, nothing played when I set the update timer to just a few hundred milliseconds (in the appwidget provider xml file).  Furthermore, I set break points and found out that not only was it never reaching the activity, but no break points I set would ever get triggered.  (I still haven't figured out why that is), however, logcat seemed to indicate that the activity class file was being run.

So, is there anything I can do to get an appwidget to respond to a click?  As the `onClickPendingIntent()` method is the closest I have found to a `onClick` type of method.

Comment: Hai Leif, do you solve this problem by Brain515's Methode? I have a similar problem, But the Brain's solution not work for me, Can you please help me?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

First, add a static variable with a constant.

```
public static String YOUR_AWESOME_ACTION = "YourAwesomeAction";
```

Then you need to add the action to the intent before you add the intent to the pending intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, widget.class);
intent.setAction(YOUR_AWESOME_ACTION);
```

(Where widget.class is the class of your AppWidgetProvider, your current class)

You then need to create a PendingIntent with getBroadcast

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

Set the onClickPendingIntent for the clickable view in your widget

```
remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetFrameLayout, pendingIntent);
```

Next, override the onReceive method in the same class:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 super.onReceive(context, intent);
```

And then respond to your button presses by querying the intent returned for your action within the onReceive method:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(YOUR_AWESOME_ACTION)) {
   //do some really cool stuff here
}
```

And that should do it!

Comment: where this line ( Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExampleActivity.class);) is place? What does the widget.class contain? I guess ExampleActivity is what we want to launch

Comment: Edited the reply to a method some extra steps that are needed for this to work. The getBroadcast is important for the PendingIntent to be broadcast, rather than getActivity from the example.

Comment: Why PendingIntent.getBroadcast vs PendingIntent.getActivity?

Comment: .getActivity is used to open an activity e.g. when you click an object in the widget

Comment: Use a LocalBroadcastManager instead of generic broadcasts

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to use PendingIntent with LocalBroadcastManager

Comment: The PendingIntent.getBroadcast is very important!

Comment: What to do in widget.class? I have stumbled into many posts on stackoverflow but failed. Please guide.

Comment: @TheOnlyAnil - it's like this -> `<class_name>.class`

Comment: can I use this when refreshing the widget?

Answer (score 2):

Leave the **onUpdate** method as it was and copy-paste the logic to **updateAppWidget**.

```
static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {

    // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity when clicked
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExampleActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget_provider_layout);
    // Widgets allow click handlers to only launch pending intents
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);
    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}
```

PS. **PendingIntent** is just "box" for an Intent, that allows *other applications* to have access and run that Intent in your application.

Comment: Why do you do this for every widget update? Surely it just needs to be done once?