# Forcing An Android Widget to Update

Tags: android, android-widget

I have been trying relentlessly to figure out to have my widget update with a press of the button that is on the widget. The widget displays the current RAM remaining, CPU level, and Battery charge.

The code to determine those values work well. I just cant get it to update when I press the button. I have tried these methods :

[Force Android widget to update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748613/force-android-widget-to-update) - both methods shown

[Android: How do I force the update of all widgets of a particular kind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304387/android-how-do-i-force-the-update-of-all-widgets-of-a-particular-kind)

[Clickable widgets in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748590/clickable-widgets-in-android/)

And an alarm manager

None of them have worked.

My XML for my widget layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/widgetbg">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/widgetCPU"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/derp"   
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/widgetRam"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/derp"   
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/widgetBat"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/derp"   
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/widgetUpdate"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/button_send" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

And the method I would like to call when the button is pressed :

```
    public class AppWidget extends AppwidgetProvider
    {
    //...
         public void update(Context c, AppWidgetManager a)
         { 
          //...
         }
    //...
    }
```

How would I be able to call the update method when my button is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

register a listener, e.g. in your onCreate() method:

```
     findViewById(R.id.widgetUpdate).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                        update();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there an onCreate() for a widget?

Comment: no but for the activity in which it resides. Or where do you inflate the layout?

Comment: I have created a service to update my widget and I use the line 

RemoteViews rvs = new RemoteViews(cn.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout

to inflate it.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the AppWidget part there. Your only chance then is to add a PendingIntent to the widget as whole and do your update in the intent receiver.

Comment: I tried the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748613/force-android-widget-to-update. With no avail. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: sorry, the only thing I did from a widget was open my activity

Answer (score 1):

You could add an onClickListener to the button, and call the update method from within the listener.

Check out [This link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) for more info on the interface