# Cannot send pending intent from widget, SendIntentException

Tags: android, android-intent, widget, android-pendingintent

I want to send a broadcast from my widget with this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
   RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
   Intent x = new Intent();
   if (isActive == true) {
      views.setImageViewResource(R.id.w_image, R.drawable.w_bild);
      x.setAction("de.bulling.smstalk.DISABLE");
   } else {
      views.setImageViewResource(R.id.w_image, R.drawable.w_bild_off);
      x.setAction("de.bulling.smstalk.ENABLE");
   }
   PendingIntent z = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, x, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
   views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.w_image, z);
   appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
E/RemoteViews(18176): Cannot send pending intent: 
E/RemoteViews(18176): android.content.IntentSender$SendIntentException
E/RemoteViews(18176):   at android.app.ContextImpl.startIntentSender(ContextImpl.java:640)
E/RemoteViews(18176):   at android.widget.RemoteViews$SetOnClickPendingIntent$1.onClick(RemoteViews.java:157)
E/RemoteViews(18176):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
E/RemoteViews(18176):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
E/RemoteViews(18176):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/RemoteViews(18176):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/RemoteViews(18176):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/RemoteViews(18176):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/RemoteViews(18176):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/RemoteViews(18176):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/RemoteViews(18176):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/RemoteViews(18176):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
E/RemoteViews(18176):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method
```

What's the reason for this? Do you have any idea?
Thanks,
Marc

/edit: I found the answer: It has to be Intent x = new Intent(context, WidgetClass.class);

Comment: You should mark your question as self-answered. You'll even get a medal for doing so.

Comment: Yeah, but I have to wait 8 hours before I can do that :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer: It has to be Intent x = new Intent(context, WidgetClass.class);

Answer (score 13):

I got this error too:

```
RemoteViews: Cannot send pending intent:  
RemoteViews: android.content.IntentSender$SendIntentException 
RemoteViews: at android.app.ContextImpl.startIntentSender()
```

The solution was to set a **unique requestCode** for each (sending) PendingIntent, and for this I used the provided **appWidgetId** instead of just using a **0** each time.

*getBroadCast()*

> pendingActionIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, **widgetId**,
> intentAction, pendingFlag );

*getActivity()*

> pendingActionIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, **widgetId**,
> intentAction, pendingFlag);

For some unknown reason it says it "currently not used" in the documentation?

> **requestCode**  Private request code for the sender (currently not used).

but it works;)

Comment: I think the request codes are used to match updates and replacements via PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT and PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: And for some reason a request code of 0 doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think the request codes are used to match updates and replacements via `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` and `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`.