# how to present a toast when a widget is clicked?

Tags: android, widget, onclick, toast

I need to do a simple widget that presents a Toast when clicking on it.
My problem is that I cant find how to get or create an "oncreate" action. i see the examples with the pending intent that opens the web browser. But how do i simply create this: `Toast.makeText(context, "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` and make it happen every time a user clicks on the widget?
just to be clear, I mean a widget on the launcher of the phone. not a regular "button" widget etc...

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
Notification notification;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);



    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, view);
}
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: why -1?  who ever did this can explain to me whats wrong with the question?

Comment: I think somebody didn't like your initial question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `Toast.makeText(context, "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` in widget's `onClick()` method of `View.OnClickListener`

## Update:

If you use `AppWidgetProvider` so check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347986/android-widget-on-click-event) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471875/processing-more-than-one-button-click-at-android-widget) posts

Comment: There is no View.onClickListener in a class that is extending AppWidgetProvider. there is only setOnClickPendingIntent.

Comment: You should write in your question that you want to handle app_icon clicking event for more clarity.

Comment: its not app_icon clicking, its a widget clicking on the launcher.

Comment: I just meant that. Correctly formulate your question.

Comment: I formulated my question, thanx!

Comment: Next time don't forget to use key classes names in your question for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing to **show** the created `Toast`. For example:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Moreover, override the `onClick` method of your custom `View` class and pop the toast there.

---

```
public class TestButton extends Button {

    public TestButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
        super.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                  .show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, i added that a second ago. its not that.

Comment: how do i set "view.setonclicklistener" in a class that extends BroadcastReceiver. its imposible.

Comment: I'm talking about your custom View class, see my updated answer

Comment: i guess its not halping me couse im kinda new to android but i dont see how i relate the "TestButton" to the widget on the home screen?
but ill try that. thanks.

Comment: That `TestButton` is an exemplary class. The purpose is to show you how to override `onClick` of your button whean dealing with custom Views.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                   Toast.makeText(context, "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


  }
}
});
```

Comment: there is no "findviewbyid" in a class that extends BroadcastReceiver. its imposible.

Comment: if you are using BroadcastReceiver then send broadcast message on button click event in Activity.And toast in onRecive() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonToast);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Create a piece of toast.
        Toast pieceToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        // Show the toast.
        pieceToast.show();
    }
```

This is my BroadcastReciever Class:

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if(null == bundle)
            return;
        Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver",bundle.toString());
        String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String registredPhoneNumber;
        Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","State: "+ state);
        String phonenumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        System.out.println("*****Mobile Ringing*******"+phonenumber);
        if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
        {
            registredPhoneNumber = PreferenceConnector.getPhoneNumber(context);
            System.out.println("registredPhoneNumber:  "+registredPhoneNumber);
            System.out.println("phonenumber:   "+phonenumber);
            Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","Incomng Number: " + phonenumber);
            if(phonenumber.equals(registredPhoneNumber)){
                System.out.println("Entered...");
                String info = "Detect Calls sample application\nIncoming number: " + phonenumber;
                if(isMyServiceRunning(context)){
                    context.stopService(new Intent(context,com.visiomaticamericas.visitormobile.services.LaunchServiceActivity.class));
                    System.out.println("******Service Stopped*********");
                }
                Intent i = new Intent(context,com.services.LaunchServiceActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("delay",500L);
                context.startService(i);
                System.out.println("*****Service Started*****");
                Toast.makeText(context, info, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Here, I called my activity class.. and I did my widget design in My activity class..

Comment: how do i set "view.setonclicklistener" in a class that extends BroadcastReceiver.  its imposible.

Comment: you are still doing button.setOnClickListener!!   you can not do that in a AppWidgetProvider!  non of you read the comments :)

Comment: We are not able do this.. So, you just call your activity class from OnRecievemethod of your broadcastReciever extended class. You just design you UI under Activity class.. See My question edited..

Answer (score 0):

this may helps ,  here need  to pass context  and get Onclick Event with your widget

Toast.makeText(context, "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: how do i set "view.setonclicklistener" in a class that extends BroadcastReceiver. its imposible.

Comment: you cannot even do "findViewById" in a AppWidgetProvider!

Comment: see my question again, its a home screen widget!  not a regular button. u just cant do onclicklistener.

Answer (score 0):

folks my VS environment is VS 2017 with Xamarin .

> ```
>    private void DisplayMessage(string DisplayMsgText)
>     {
>         Toast.MakeText(this.ApplicationContext, DisplayMsgText, ToastLength.Short).Show();
>     }
> ```

and use this function to show message at device screen
like below:

> DisplayMessage("Vibrate button pressed");