# How to show a toast message when widget is clicked in android

Tags: android, android-widget

I created a widget app and it works perfectly.  Now i need to show a toast message while clicking on widget.  Is it possible i tried with below code.

```
public void updateView(Context context) {  
     RemoteViews thisViews = new RemoteViews(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
     thisViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.relativeLayout1, actionPendingIntent(context));
     thisViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text, batteryLevel);  
     thisViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView1, widgetImageFrame);  
     ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, BatteryStatusWidgetActivity.class);  
     AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(thisWidget, thisViews);  
}  

public static PendingIntent actionPendingIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,LaunchActivity.class);
        intent.setAction("LAUNCH_ACTIVITY");
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
```

The above sample will launch an activity, but i need just a toast message.

thanks in advance

Comment: you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511940/how-to-present-a-toast-when-a-widget-is-clicked

Comment: @Shriram Above link not solved my issue