# Toast on widget click

Tags: android, android-widget

Googled through the whole Internet and found nothing so I need your help again.
I created an Android widget with `android:background` declared in the layout file.
I want to show a toast on click so I did this:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And yes, it works, but only in the widget chooser when I choose my widget. How can I show that toast on every click?

Comment: There's really no need to search the *whole* internet, all you need to know about Android you can find on http://developer.android.com/ and http://stackoverflow.com/

For this question, you should probably read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347986/android-widget-on-click-event