# How to display a toast on image button click in android widget

Tags: android, android-widget, appwidgetprovider

I'm creating a widget that had a button! When I click on a button. It just reads my location and toasts it! 
It should not open any activity! 
Just a toast on the button click in the widget!
Need help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to call

`Toast.makeText(context, "Hi there!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

in widget's `onClick()` method of `View.OnClickListener`

If using `AppWidgetProvider` take a look at  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347986/android-widget-on-click-event) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471875/processing-more-than-one-button-click-at-android-widget)

Comment: For widget it extends from Appwidgetprovider!, Does the findviewbyId work in widget class?? I tried XML attribute android:onClick also, but couldn't make it work,, where as the toast is working fine in onUpdate, onEnabled and onDisabled methods

Comment: I did refer! I'm positive for invoking an activity on image button press! But I need a toast! I invoke a toast on a image button click!