# Changing TextView text in an Android Widget

Tags: android, widget

I’m developing an android widget. In the widget I have a text field and two buttons. When I press button1 I want the text field to show a certain text, like “one,” and if I click button2, the text field will show like “2.”

the onUpdate() looks like this :

```
 @Override public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds){ super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds); 

    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CalculatorReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

    PendingIntent actionPendingIntent =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.one, actionPendingIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews); }
```

and the onReceive() method looks like this:

```
@Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)){

         Toast.makeText(context, "Hi I'm 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }}
```

Now, in the widget, I’m only able to show a Toast when a button pressed, but I want to get the textView and change its value. How do I get and change the textView?

Comment: this question may be useful
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944553/android-appwidget-textview-not-updating

Comment: this [question][1] may be useful!!!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944553/android-appwidget-textview-not-updating

Answer (score 6):

- You can't get the values of views from your widget.
- You can update `TextView` of the widget by using `RemoteViews`
  `remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view_id, "Your text");`

Comment: Hi, yea I know, but how do I update the TextView if the button pressed? I’m only able to recognize button press using: remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.one, actionPendingIntent); and the actionPendingIntent will implement onReceive() method. i can’t get the TextView in the onRecieve() method because it will give me NullPointerException in the Receiver calass.

Comment: You can create again the `RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main)` in `onReceive` method and then update the text view. Or i missed your question..

Comment: After this, also do `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add the below lines in onReceive()

remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_appNameView, "text view updated");

ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, 
WidgetProvider.class);
                     AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(componentName, remoteViews);