# Android: Clickable imageview widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to make a very simple widget:

It must consist from just one image view

1) on incoming sms it should change the image

2) on click it also should change the image

I tried to make it using ImageButton but failed: there were problems with changing the image on sms received event: new image had wrong scale.

Anyway now I want to make an ImageView without anything else.

The problem is that I can't handle onClick event:

I've got a running service which should handle all events: sms received and click:

widget provider:

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        context.stopService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
        super.onDisabled(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                     int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
            Intent widgetClickIntent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
            widgetClickIntent.setAction(UpdateService.ACTION_ON_CLICK);
            PendingIntent pendingIntentViewClick = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, widgetClickIntent, 0);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_imageview, pendingIntentViewClick);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
        }
    }
}
```

service:

```
public class UpdateService extends Service {
    static final String ACTION_SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    static final String ACTION_ON_CLICK = "android.MyWidget.ACTION_ON_CLICK";

    private final static IntentFilter intentFilter;

    static {
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_SMS_RECEIVED);
        intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_ON_CLICK);
    }


    public final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(ACTION_SMS_RECEIVED)) {
                reactOnSms(context);
            }
            if (action.equals(ACTION_ON_CLICK)) {
                onCLick(context);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void reactOnSms(Context context) {
        // doSomething
    }

    public void onCLick(Context context) {
        // doSomething
    }
```

Manifest:

```
    <receiver a:name="..."...>
        <intent-filter>
            <action a:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            <action a:name="android.MyWidget.ACTION_ON_CLICK"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data a:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                   a:resource="@xml/my_widget_provider_info"/>
    </receiver>
    <service a:name=".UpdateService"
            a:label="UpdateService">

        <intent-filter>
            <action a:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            <action a:name="android.MyWidget.ACTION_ON_CLICK"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I tried this [Clickable widgets in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748590/clickable-widgets-in-android)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution.

Sorry for those of you who read the question. Too much code inside, I understand.

The problem was that UpdateService was not the real handler of the broadcast intent. Anonymous implementation of BroadcastReceiver made all the work.

So the problem was in this code (widgetProvider):

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                 int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
        // wrong:
        // Intent widgetClickIntent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
        // widgetClickIntent.setAction(UpdateService.ACTION_ON_CLICK);
        // PendingIntent pendingIntentViewClick = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, widgetClickIntent, 0);
        // correct:
        Intent widgetClickIntent = new Intent(UpdateService.ACTION_ON_CLICK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentViewClick = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, widgetClickIntent, 0);
        ///////
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_imageview, pendingIntentViewClick);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
    }
}
```