# Widget onClick is not working properly

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, widget, android-pendingintent

Wellcome all

I want that when the user press on the widget, the widget stops itself, and when the user press again, the widget put ON his functions

i'm using the solution of this post to achieve onClick on my widget: [Clickable widgets in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748590/clickable-widgets-in-android)

The solution works fine in android 2.2 phone and android 4.1 phone but doesn't works on Nexus One with android 2.3.6. I click on the widget but nothing happens...

This is my full widget class:

```
        public class mWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider{         
            public static String ACTION_WIDGET_CLICK = "ActionWidgetClick"; 
            public static final String ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE = "AUTO_UPDATE";

            DecimalFormatSymbols symbols;
            DecimalFormat tempDecimalFormat;
            int pMaxFreq=-1;
            String cCurrentFreq=null;
            int freq = 0;
            float usage =-1;
            BufferedReader freqBufferedReader;
            PowerManager pm;
            RemoteViews remoteViews;
            ComponentName thisWidget;   
            WidgetAlarm widgetAlarm;
            ActivityManager manager;

            @Override
            public void onDisabled(Context context) {
                super.onDisabled(context);
                context.stopService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));

                //stop alarm
                widgetAlarm = new WidgetAlarm(context.getApplicationContext());
                widgetAlarm.stopAlarm();

                System.out.println("XXXXX onDISABLED");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
                super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);

                System.out.println("XXXXX onDELETED");
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
                super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

                context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class)); 

                remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
                thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, mWidgetProvider.class );

                //preparamos el evento para cuando el usuario presiona en el widget, ese evento será recibido en onReceive()
                Intent active = new Intent(context, mWidgetProvider.class);
                active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_CLICK);
                PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
                remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.fondo, actionPendingIntent);           

                AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget( thisWidget, remoteViews );       

                // start alarm
                widgetAlarm = new WidgetAlarm(context.getApplicationContext());
                widgetAlarm.startAlarm();

                System.out.println("XXXXX onUPDATE");       
            }       

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
                if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_CLICK)){
                    switchWidget(context);
                }else if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE)){

                    symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMAN);
                    symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
                    tempDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#", symbols);      

                    pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
                    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
                    thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, mWidgetProvider.class );

                    if (pm.isScreenOn()){               
                     /*
                                 here i do some work to update the textviews of the widget
                                 */

                        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget( thisWidget, remoteViews );
                        System.out.println("XXXXX UPDATING WIDGET");
                    }
                }else{
                    super.onReceive(context, intent);
                }

                System.out.println("XXXXX onRECEIVE: "+intent.getAction());
            }

            @Override
            public void onEnabled(Context context) {
                super.onEnabled(context);           

                System.out.println("XXXXX onENABLED");
            }   

            public void switchWidget(Context context){
                symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMAN);
                symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
                tempDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#", symbols);      

                remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
                thisWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), mWidgetProvider.class.getName());
                widgetAlarm = new WidgetAlarm(context.getApplicationContext());
                if (isMyServiceRunning(context)==true){ //si el widget está encendido la apagamos
                    context.stopService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));          
                    widgetAlarm.stopAlarm();
                    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.freq,"HERE I CHANGE THE VALUE");
                }
                else{ //si el widget está apagado lo encendemos
                    context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class)); 
                    widgetAlarm.startAlarm();
                            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.freq,"HERE I CHANGE THE VALUE");
                }
                AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(thisWidget,remoteViews);
            }

            private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context context) {
                manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
                    if (UpdateService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

            public void getpMaxFreq(){
                int freq = 0;
                try{            
                    //HERE I DO SOME WORK               
                }
                catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }
```

PD: i tryed also putting the intent in `onEnabled()` function, with the same result... didn't work on Nexus One with 2.3.6 Android version

greetings