# click listener on android widget Button

Tags: android, button, android-widget, onclick

I am new to android development.
I want add click listener on button in widget.
I am updating widget in service.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you should look into making a [*clickable widget*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748590/clickable-widgets-in-android).

This involves using:

> remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetFrameLayout,
>   pendingIntent);

Comment: I am using service to update the widget
So what should be the pending intent

Comment: Not too familiar with the widget callback system. I'd look into the link though. Sorry if it didn't help much.

Comment: Please upvote the answer as well if you can! thanks and I'm glad I helped. :)