# Need widget button example to display a dialog box or Toast

Tags: android, android-widget

I wanted to create a widget with a button. When it's clicked, how can make it perform a function like displaying a dialog box or a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)?

Comment: You'll have to show a bit more effort than that. The answer can surely be found here on SO - digging for the answer (not just asking for it) is part of the fun. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

#### Code

```
Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); // id which is defined inside your XML file below
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Your Toast or dialog code goes here
    }
});
```

#### XML

Inside the [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) file, define the button as:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
    android:text = "my Button"
 />
```

#### Remember

The user defined **id should be defined** with `@+id`, like `android:id="@+id/button1"`, not with `@id`, like `android:id="@id/button1"`.

Answer (score 0):

A widget works with [remote views](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) that send intents.
You need to set a [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) see the next [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609500/click-listener-on-android-widget-button).

After your context (Activity, Service,...) recieve the intent you can make a Toast or a Dialog.