# How to make ListView clickable in Android Widget?

Tags: android

I am a newbie in Android development and I am faced with a problem which I can't figure out. I am following [this](http://laaptu.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/populate-appwidget-listview-with-remote-datadata-from-web/) link. It is a simple widget which has a listView which shows harcoded feed.

I wanted to make the widget interactive. So I came up with a solution as follows: I created a `Intent`, associated with it a Action and Broadcasted it with `PendingIntent`. Now I tried to catch that `Intent` in the `onReceive()` function of the `WidgetProvider.java` class.

I thought this approach is great except the fact that onUpdate function is called every 30 minutes. I am not sure even if it works after 30 minutes, haven't tried it. So I can't figure out how do I achieve this.

Basically I wanted to make it into widget, on which if clicked, it launches another activity. And can you also tell when is the onReceive function of the AppWidgetProvider called.

Comment: Have you checked the following post?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748590/clickable-widgets-in-android?rq=1

Comment: @BenSteele: yes I have. Actually this was the post which gave me the idea of this technique. But sadly it didn't work.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Comment: You can also force an update by getting an `AppWidgetManager` and calling `updateAppWidget` with the app widget id.