# How to open new activity from widget without showing old ones from activity stack?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

There're two activities in my app: A and B. A is opened in a usual way (from launcher). B is opened from widget. Also B has "dialog" theme, so I can see what's under it.

When app isn't runned and I open B from widget, everything is correct and I see launcher under B.

When app is runned and I open B from widget, I see A under it. **But I need launcher to be under B, not A. How to get this?**

*UPDATE 1*

Here's what I get (when I click the widget)

[image]

And here's what I need

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution.

1. Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748590/clickable-widgets-in-android)
2. Finish the A (I've static field in A which stores its instance. So I just use a.finish())
3. simply startActivity() (don't forget about Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to launch this activity with the following flags:

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`

so on your widget intent you add them as normal:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

Comment: Doesn't help. There's still A under B

Answer (score 0):

Try to build your PendingIntent using TaskStackBuilder from the support library.

Alternatively, add these flags to your Intent:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME
```